# Nested Dictionary Parsing - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, dictionary, amazon-ec2

I have a dictionary of dictionaries. I need to iterate through the parent dictionary until I find the nested dict which contains a specify key and value pair. The key and value pair that I care about is:

```
key=Key, value=Name
```

Once I've located the proper nested dict by finding this `Name` tag, I then need to pull out that nested dicts `value` of `key=Value`.

```
key=Value, value=pz-beanstalkd-asg-ec2
```

Ultimately, I need `pz-beanstalkd-asg-ec2` which is the `Value` of my EC2 instances  `Name` tag.

The below code below prints out my dictionary...

How do I do get to `pz-beanstalkd-asg-ec2` using Python3?

```
print ('lenth of dict=' + str(len(instanceTagsDict['Tags'])))
    for x in range(0, len(instanceTagsDict['Tags'])):
        print('x=' + str(x))
        for key, value in instanceTagsDict['Tags'][x].items():
            print('key=' + key + ', value=' + value)


lenth of dict=5
x=0
key=Key, value=AWSService
key=ResourceId, value=i-0dd3a48d19fbc0aa7
key=ResourceType, value=instance
key=Value, value=ec2
x=1
key=Key, value=Application
key=ResourceId, value=i-0dd3a48d19fbc0aa7
key=ResourceType, value=instance
key=Value, value=myallocator
x=2
key=Key, value=Environment
key=ResourceId, value=i-0dd3a48d19fbc0aa7
key=ResourceType, value=instance
key=Value, value=production
x=3
key=Key, value=Name
key=ResourceId, value=i-0dd3a48d19fbc0aa7
key=ResourceType, value=instance
key=Value, value=pz-beanstalkd-asg-ec2
x=4
key=Key, value=aws:autoscaling:groupName
key=ResourceId, value=i-0dd3a48d19fbc0aa7
key=ResourceType, value=instance
key=Value, value=pz-beanstalkd-asg
```

The function I'm calling is describe_tags, docs here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_tags

**Return type is** 
dict

**Response Syntax is**

```
{
    'NextToken': 'string',
    'Tags': [
        {
            'Key': 'string',
            'ResourceId': 'string',
            'ResourceType': 'customer-gateway'|'dhcp-options'|'image'|'instance'|'internet-gateway'|'network-acl'|'network-interface'|'reserved-instances'|'route-table'|'snapshot'|'spot-instances-request'|'subnet'|'security-group'|'volume'|'vpc'|'vpn-connection'|'vpn-gateway',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you just give a sample of the json? It would be much easier to test.

Comment: Your example is a list of dicts not dict of dicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def findval(mykey, myval):
  for item in instanceTagsDict['Tags']:
    if mykey in item and item[mykey] == myval:
      print(item['Value'])
```

Do It!

```
>>> findval('Key', 'Name')
pz-beanstalkd-asg-ec2
```